# kineticjs dragable limit with dragBounds - not running

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

i want drag my stage with limit top, left, right, bottom with dragBounds but it's not working

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 363,
    draggable: true,
    dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
        var newY = pos.y < 50 ? 50 : pos.y;
        return {
          x: pos.x,
          y: newY
        };
    },
    dragBounds: { // it's not running
        top: 10,
        bottom: 300,
        left: 0,
        right: 500   
    }
});
```

here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/kien16/aUWY2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dragBounds` is not in the current release of KineticJS...use `dragBoundFunc`

See an example here: [Kineticjs dragBoundFunc for a rect in a rect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854001/kineticjs-dragboundfunc-for-a-rect-in-a-rect/15865422#15865422)

Here's a tutorial from the kineticJS site: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-shapes-horizontally-or-vertically-tutorial/

Comment: +1 the dragBounds property was dropped in favor of dragBoundFunc, which enables limitless drag and drop behavior