# Groups of shapes can be dragged outside the layers and stage in kineticjs

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

Groups of shapes can be dragged outside the KineticJS layers and stage and are lost. 
Below tutorial (dragging) works differently in ie9.
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's true...shapes can be dragged outside their group.

If you want them contained inside the group, you can set the `dragBoundFunc` function on the objects:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-shapes-horizontally-or-vertically-tutorial/

Comment: I want the groups to stop dragging outside the layer/stage. They shouldn't be lost if the user clicks outside the stage.

Comment: BTW my shapes are not draggable, only the groups are.

Comment: Same is true for groups...set dragBoundFunc for the group to keep them on stage. And yes, having the default drag be infinite is a bit uncommon, but it would optimize speed. Your fix is fairly simple...code a function that creates new groups and also assigns a dragBoundFunc contained to the stage.

Comment: Thanks markE. I found the answer I was looking out for in the below link, again answered by you. Ofcourse its using a dragboundbound function. [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854001/kineticjs-dragboundfunc-for-a-rect-in-a-rect/15865422#15865422