# KineticJS dragBound inside a Polygon

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I'm using a KineticJS to create an application. The problem is I need to apply dragBoundFunc to an image inside a polygon so the user can't move the image outside. The polygon might by any shape, like this, for example:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dselkirk/QaX84/)

```
var polygon = new Kinetic.Polygon({
    points: [-5, 0, 75, 0, 70, 10, 70, 60, 60, 90, 61, 92, 64, 96, 66, 100, 67, 105, 67, 110, 67, 113, 66, 117, 64, 120, 63, 122, 61, 124, 58, 127, 55, 129, 53, 130, 50, 130, 20, 130, 17, 130, 15, 129, 12, 127, 9, 124, 7, 122, 6, 120, 4, 117, 3, 113, 3, 110, 3, 105, 4, 100, 6, 96, 9, 92, 10, 90, 0, 60, 0, 10],
    fill: 'none',
    stroke: '#000',
    strokeWidth: 0,
    name: 'polygon',
    draggable: false
});
```

What are the algorithms to check, if the image is inside the polygon? Or what is the better way to solve the problem?

Comment: hi here is post similar might help u start.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854001/kineticjs-dragboundfunc-for-a-rect-in-a-rect/15865422#15865422

Comment: Thank you! But this algorithm is for a rectangle, I can't apply it for a polygon...

Comment: its just help u start just do - around for polygon needs accordingly my friend.

Comment: Yep, I've chosen to get bounding rectangle around my polygon: http://jsfiddle.net/dselkirk/nNJd7/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your complex path presents a problem**

The problem is that complex paths (like your example) require extensive calculations to determine if the inside object has escaped outside the path.

And remember that these calculations must be done with every mousemove event.  Mousemove events can fire dozens of times each second.

I have some experience with KineticJS and I believe that bounding objects inside your complex path will fail because the calculations can't be completed before the object has been dragged outside the path.

**An alternative**

As an alternative (if you design permits), you could create a bounding rectangle around your complex path and use that bounding rectangle to contain the inside object.

Similarly, you could create a bounding circle around your complex path and use that bounding circle to contain the inside object.

Rectangular and circular bounding areas can be checked quickly enough to contain the object before it escapes.

**I do have another alternative for you.**

Since your inside object is a rectangle, you could check if all 4 corners of the rectangle are inside your complex path.  If all 4 corners are inside the path, your rectangle is *probably but not necessarily inside your complex path.*

You can use native canvas's context.isPointInPath(corner1X,corner1Y) to check the 4 corners.

This solution will require you to:

- Maintain a separate offscreen html canvas.
- Draw your complex path on that offscreen canvas.
- Use context.isPointInPath to test your rectangle's 4 corners.